# remote insert using local select in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have one database with table t1 at local server and one database with table t2 and t3 at remote server. I would like to create a function on local database that can insert data on remote server using local data.

Example:
local table - t1 (xid, newxid)

remote table - t2 (id, xid, iname)

remote table to be populate:
t3 (t2.id, t1.newxid, t2.iname)

criteria: t1.xid = t2.xid

I know about dblink, but not sure how to use it specifically for above requirements.

Note: I know how to do local insert with remote select.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html)
- writable [Foreign Data Wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html)